# Is there an explorer like Etherscan for Remix JS VM sandbox blockchain

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, remix, etherscan

I created a contract and did some transactions. I would like to explore the transactions in the sandbox blockchain in my brower (Chrome). But the tx hash is not found in the REMIX VM Debugger http://etherscan.io/remix?txhash= ... ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try Puppeth. It is for managing your own fully featured private Ethereum network, with nodes, genesis set up, tools and monitoring, wallets, faucets, single dashboard, and more. Here is a DevCon3 talk about it:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5RcjYPTG9g&list=PLaM7G4Llrb7xnKb_SeaKZ27opvaIjlBv5

Comment: Thanks! Puppeth looks very promising. I don't understand if I can run this network by myself on a single PC like in a VM environment or what do I need in terms of hardware? Do I need some friends to use their PC's as nodes? Also, what is the advantage of Puppeth over using a public Testnet like Ropsten?